# AWK Assignment to variable

Tags: unix

I am looking for assignment of value of variable to another variable in awk.

Below is the example

```
if (substr($0,1,1) == "4") 
{
    COUNT_DETAIL_SEG++
    SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS=$(COUNT_DETAIL_SEG)
    print "Sum of detail records is" SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS
}
```

Suppose if 1st character of line comes out to be "4" then i want to increment value of `COUNT_DETAIL_SEG` and assign this value to `SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS` and thereby print it.
But i am unable to retain this value.
Can anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of

```
SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS=$(COUNT_DETAIL_SEG)
```

you want :

```
SUM_OF_DETAIL_RCDS=COUNT_DETAIL_SEG
```

because in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), when you put `$(INT)`, you refer no the N'th column of the current input line.

Comment: Thanks to accept the answer if it fit your needs. That's hos stackoverflow work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do this at the start of the awk statement.  @sputnick is on the right track.

```
awk -v var="$bash_var" '{ awk code here}'
```

This will use the awk internal variable `var` instead of the shell variable `bash_var`.